# Optimising an OR query on a left join table

Tags: sql, postgresql, indexing

I have this query on table **A** which does a left join on an associated table **B** and pulls records which match certain conditions on **A** *OR* certain conditions on **B**:

```
SELECT  A.*, B.status FROM "A" 
LEFT JOIN B ON B.a_id = A.id AND B.b_field = 20371
WHERE "A"."type" = 'SomeValue' AND "A"."deleted_at" IS NULL AND 
      (A.a_field = 20371 OR A.another_field = 69074 OR B.id IS NOT NULL) 
ORDER BY "A"."updated_at" DESC LIMIT 10 OFFSET 0;
```

Here is the explain:

```
Limit  (cost=234623.62..234624.83 rows=10 width=635) (actual time=4034.840..4034.984 rows=10 loops=1)
  ->  Gather Merge  (cost=234623.62..344565.43 rows=909175 width=635) (actual time=4034.839..4034.982 rows=10 loops=1)
        Workers Planned: 5
        Workers Launched: 0
        ->  Sort  (cost=233623.54..234078.13 rows=181835 width=635) (actual time=4033.536..4033.540 rows=10 loops=1)
              Sort Key: A.updated_at DESC
              Sort Method: top-N heapsort  Memory: 34kB
              ->  Hash Left Join  (cost=113.31..229694.15 rows=181835 width=635) (actual time=5.680..4033.139 rows=79 loops=1)
                    Hash Cond: (A.id = B.a_id)
                    Filter: ((A.a_field = 20371) OR (A.another_field = 69074) OR (B.id IS NOT NULL))
                    Rows Removed by Filter: 860017
                    ->  Parallel Seq Scan on A  (cost=0.00..228898.94 rows=181835 width=635) (actual time=0.011..3833.346 rows=860096 loops=1)
                          Filter: ((deleted_at IS NULL) AND ((type)::text = 'SomeValue'::text))
                          Rows Removed by Filter: 5265254
                    ->  Hash  (cost=112.92..112.92 rows=31 width=8) (actual time=0.107..0.108 rows=79 loops=1)
                          Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 12kB
                          ->  Index Scan using index_B_on_b_field on B B  (cost=0.42..112.92 rows=31 width=8) (actual time=0.014..0.087 rows=79 loops=1)
                                Index Cond: (b_field = 20371)
Planning Time: 0.790 ms
Execution Time: 4035.090 ms
```

As you can see Postgres is not utilizing any of the indexes on the main table to discount a major proportion of records on A (A.type, A.deleted_at, etc) because it has to scan through the **B** records.

Here's the query without the OR condition:

```
SELECT  A.*, B.status FROM "A" 
LEFT JOIN B ON B.a_id = A.id AND B.b_field = 20371
WHERE "A"."type" = 'SomeValue' AND "A"."deleted_at" IS NULL AND 
      (A.a_field = 20371 OR A.another_field = 69074) 
ORDER BY "A"."updated_at" DESC LIMIT 10 OFFSET 0;
```

And the explain analyze:

```
Limit  (cost=1397.52..1397.55 rows=10 width=635) (actual time=0.018..0.019 rows=0 loops=1)
  ->  Sort  (cost=1397.52..1397.64 rows=48 width=635) (actual time=0.017..0.018 rows=0 loops=1)
        Sort Key: A.updated_at DESC
        Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 25kB
        ->  Hash Left Join  (cost=128.65..1396.49 rows=48 width=635) (actual time=0.013..0.014 rows=0 loops=1)
              Hash Cond: (A.id = B.a_id)
              ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on A  (cost=15.33..1282.98 rows=48 width=635) (actual time=0.012..0.013 rows=0 loops=1)
                    Recheck Cond: ((a_field = 20371) OR (another_field = 69074))
                    Filter: ((deleted_at IS NULL) AND ((type)::text = 'SomeValue'::text))
                    ->  BitmapOr  (cost=15.33..15.33 rows=325 width=0) (actual time=0.011..0.012 rows=0 loops=1)
                          ->  Bitmap Index Scan on index_A_on_a_field  (cost=0.00..10.87 rows=325 width=0) (actual time=0.006..0.006 rows=0 loops=1)
                                Index Cond: (a_field = 20371)
                          ->  Bitmap Index Scan on index_A_on_another_field  (cost=0.00..4.44 rows=1 width=0) (actual time=0.005..0.005 rows=0 loops=1)
                                Index Cond: (another_field = 69074)
              ->  Hash  (cost=112.92..112.92 rows=31 width=4) (never executed)
                    ->  Index Scan using index_B_on_b_field on B B  (cost=0.42..112.92 rows=31 width=4) (never executed)
                          Index Cond: (b_field = 20371)
Planning Time: 0.552 ms
Execution Time: 0.104 ms
```

Is there a way we could re-write this query or enable Postgres to utilize some of the indexes on the main A table?

Comment: Table B is not needed in the main query, you can move it into an `EXISTS(...)` term.

Comment: I do need it. Edited the query to add a column from B in the select clause. @wildplasser

Comment: So, we were optimising the wrong query (plan)?

Comment: Nope, the queryplan is correct

Comment: "enable Postgres to utilize some of the indexes on the main A table"  You haven't told us what those are.

Comment: Step#1 in reading a query plan: compare the expected vs the observed rowcounts. And these are very different here.

Answer (score 3):

You could try expanding to `UNION`:

```
SELECT  A.* FROM "A" 
LEFT JOIN B ON B.a_id = A.id AND B.b_field = 20371
WHERE "A"."type" = 'SomeValue' AND "A"."deleted_at" IS NULL AND 
      (A.a_field = 20371 OR A.another_field = 69074 OR B.id IS NOT NULL) 
ORDER BY "A"."updated_at" DESC LIMIT 10 OFFSET 0;
```

=>

```
SELECT  A.* 
FROM "A" 
LEFT JOIN B ON B.a_id = A.id AND B.b_field = 20371
WHERE "A"."type" = 'SomeValue' 
  AND "A"."deleted_at" IS NULL 
  AND  A.a_field = 20371  
UNION
SELECT  A.* 
FROM "A" 
LEFT JOIN B ON B.a_id = A.id AND B.b_field = 20371
WHERE "A"."type" = 'SomeValue' 
  AND "A"."deleted_at" IS NULL 
  AND  A.another_field = 69074 
UNION 
SELECT  A.* 
FROM "A" 
LEFT JOIN B ON B.a_id = A.id AND B.b_field = 20371
WHERE "A"."type" = 'SomeValue' 
  AND "A"."deleted_at" IS NULL
  AND  B.id IS NOT NULL   -- this would be the same as changing LEFT to INNER JOIN
ORDER BY "A"."updated_at" DESC LIMIT 10 OFFSET 0;
```